# Japanese kana text recognise is different on Android-Studio and Xcode

Tags: xcode, android-studio

I am going to make the japan banks list filtering, but there is some trouble is hard to fix. Here is some example images to describe the problem that i facing.

[Android Studio Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUlt8.png)

[Xcode Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxyUh.png)

Expect result:
Bank ジャパンネット should not be show on the list.

Final result:
Only Android show the ジャパンネット on the list.

As you can see, the first letter result on Android studio is different with Xcode. Android can not grab the dot next to the ｼ, so the first letter output is シ, i have checked the Android and Xcode both are using UTF-8

Comment: Are your inputs normalized the same way? macOS likes to use NFD instead of the usual NFC, so it probably decomposes U+30B8 into U+30B7 and U+3099.

Comment: @grawity Yes, it is the same input